# Why did Harry choose Ron as the keeper when he knew about extenuating circumstances?

Tags: harry-potter

In the movie *The Half Blood Prince*, at the Quidditch try outs, Gryffindor is trying to choose whether Ron or Cormac deserves to be the Keeper. Hermione casts the Confundus charm on Cormac in a low voice so that Cormac misses the ball, letting Ron get the Keeper position.

But later in the movie, Hermione and Harry have a conversation, and he says that he knows what Hermione did that day. If he knew at the time the try out was held, isn't it unfair that he still chose Ron to be the Keeper?

Comment: Just because Cormac did worse than he could've doesn't diminish the fact that Ron was perfect in his trial.  Also, Cormac's a jerk.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In the [source novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Half-Blood_Prince), Harry was deeply concerned that his best friend wouldn't make the cut. He'd already tried to clear the stadium so that he'd be under less pressure. When it came down to it, however, **Ron simply saved more goals, making him the obvious choice**.

> *‘No,’ said Harry. ‘You’ve had your go. You saved four. Ron saved five.
>   Ron’s Keeper, he won it fair and square. Get out of my way.’*

Harry apparently didn't realise that McLaggen had been hexed until later, by which time it was too late to do anything about it which, after McLaggen's tantrum, he **wasn't inclined to do anyway.**

> *‘I was better than that McLaggen anyway,’ said Ron in a highly
>   satisfied voice. ‘Did you see him lumbering off in the wrong direction
>   on his fifth? Looked like he’d been Confunded …’*
>
> ***To Harry’s surprise, Hermione turned a very deep shade of pink at
>   these words.*** Ron noticed nothing; he was too busy describing each of
>   his other penalties in loving detail.

---

In the film, Harry's conduct was far more inappropriate. He was aware of Hermione's behaviour but chose to turn a blind eye to it **simply because liked Ron better and was rooting for him to be chosen.**

> Hermione, face buried in her fingers, MUTTERS SOMETHING.
>   Cormac, at the last moment, inexplicably rolls his broom
>   to the right and the Quaffle sails over his shoulder.
>   Ron, zig-zagging crazily, nearly falls off, rights
>   himself in a panic, and deflects Ginny’s Quaffle... with
>   his forehead. As a few partisan CHEERS erupt from the
>   stands, Harry grins, then has to restrain himself.
>   Hermione opens her eyes slowly.
>
> ... [later]
>
> **HARRY:** *Yeah. I suppose I could’ve just used, I dunno... a Confundus charm?*
>
> **HERMIONE: (caught)** *That was different. It was tryouts. This was an actual match --*
>
> <sub><sup>[Half Blood Prince - Screenplay](http://screenplayexplorer.com/wp-content/scripts/Half-Blood_Prince.pdf)</sup></sub>

Comment: It always bugged me that in the movie Hermione apparently cast the Confundus charm without using her wand (or at least not waving it around).

Answer (score 28):

Firstly saving half a dozen penalty shots is a stupid way to select a member of a team. It's a tiny sample size and tells you nothing about their overall fitness or ability to read a game.

Equally, regardless of his skill, McLaggen is clearly a terrible team player: he admits to missing the last trials because he was in hospital after a ridiculous bet, so why would he be expected to show the appropriate level of commitment to the team in matches?

He also demonstrates that he is very arrogant and very likely to cause friction and disruption in the team. The fact that Harry knows and trusts Ron is not a bad reason to pick him. Having a team which get on well and trust each other is a huge advantage. This is demonstrated by the fact that Harry knew Ron well enough to help him get over his nerves with the *Felix felicis* trick before a later match.

Equally, as Captain Harry has every right to go with his gut feeling on a player; after all he wants to the team to win as much as anybody.

There is also nothing to suggest that the trial format is binding. After all Harry himself was selected on McGonagall's recommendation, so it's not as if there are strict selection rules in place.

Answer (score 10):

One other thing you might not know if you've only seen the films is that Ron actually joins the Quidditch team in *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*. After an admittedly very shaky season, he played an absolute blinder in the final match of the season, clinching victory for Gryffindor in the Quidditch cup and more than proving what he was capable of.

> Ron's euphoria at helping Gryffindor scrape the Quidditch cup was such that he couldn't settle to anything next day. All he wanted to do was talk over the match, so Harry and Hermione found it very difficult to find an opening in which to mention Grawp. Not that either of them tried very hard; neither was keen to be the one to bring Ron back to reality in quite such a brutal fashion. As it was another fine, warm day, they persuaded him to join them in revising under the beech tree at the edge of the lake, where they had less chance of being overheard than in the common room. Ron was not particularly keen on this idea at first - he was thoroughly enjoying being patted on the back by every Gryffindor who walked past his chair, not to mention the occasional outbursts of 'Weasley is our King' - but after a while he agreed that some fresh air might do him good.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* - p.620 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 31, *OWLs*

Additionally, this gave him experience of competitive house Quidditch, which McLaggen didn't have.

> 'You didn't try out last year, did you?' asked Harry, taking note of the breadth of McLaggen and thinking that he would probably block all three goalhoops without even moving.
>
> 'I was in the hospital wing when they held the trials,' said McLaggen, with something of a swagger. 'Ate a pound of Doxy eggs for a bet.'
>
> *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince* - pp.210-1 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 11, *Hermione's Helping Hand*

Comment: oh! movies really changes the plot thanks for the info

Comment: @BookStriker Cuarón’s movies are absolutely horrible. They leave out vital information and introduce glaring plot holes. If you like the stories, you should read the books—then you’ll find that they actually make sense.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Totally agree with the sentiment (although I do like the films very, very much, but that's another matter). I don't believe Cuarón did any more films than the third though? It was David Yates who did *Half-Blood Prince*

Comment: @Au101 You’re absolutely right. I guess Cuarón’s has always stood out for me as being so astoundingly poor that I’ve kind of stretched him out on to all the ones I didn’t like. Chris Columbus’ are the only two that I can actually watch with any kind of pleasure.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I did like Chris Columbus's

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Cuarón's movie**s**?! I'm only aware of Azkaban being his! And that's arguably the most visually interesting one. Excellent direction. David Yates is the biggest problem causer as far as I'm concerned. Everything magical was turned into a cartoony video-game when he signed on. R.I.P Chris Columbus' very British, warming, detailed Potterverse.

Comment: @GhotiandChips Yeah, the plurality was my bad. I actually thought Yates was better than Cuarón, though still an awful far cry from Columbus. Everything after _CoS_ was a cartoony Hollywood video-game with about as much depth as a Saharan puddle. :-(

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Pains me to hear that, having great respect for Alfonso's visual style, especially since it was very grounded in reality and gritty (which was special **back then**) and had physical props, puppetry and other forms of convincing, immersive practical visual effects, but it's undeniable that it was a 180º from the previous two (which I have to say I hated when I was a kid watching it in the cinema), but as someone with actual taste, now have come to appreciate. At least we agree about Yates haha, shame about Fantastic Beasts pentalogy being helmed by him, huh?

Comment: To be fair, the books got a lot longer after the first couple, and yet (apart from Hallows) their stories had to fit inside a movie of roughly the same length. It's unfortunate but inevitable that important bits of plot were dropped.

Comment: Most of the movies are quite good if you've read the books first.  I haven't tried to look for things in the movies that only make sense given some info that was only in the books, because I personally wanted to enjoy them for a single viewing, not to find fault with them or to watch them repeatedly.

Comment: Woah. I think I found your comments useful. But for me, I watch the movies first before reading the books. It helps me imagine the character's faces.